# Cannot open office documents from internet

Tags: office, 2019, network

I have a local Sharepoint 2016 installation.
I publish a sharepoint site to the internet through a reverse proxy.

When opening documents from any libraries, I get the message *"There are network issues stopping in my document. Please try again later*"
[image: error thumbnail]

However, manually downloading a document works correctly.

This error does not occur on the internal network.

Could someone please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Which reverse proxy do you use?

Comment: Citrix Netscaler SDX